# Cargo deploy ROOT.war in a remote server

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, deployment, cargo

I am trying to do a remote deploy on a running tomcat 5.5.27  using [cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Deploying+to+a+running+container)

On the build server in run `mvn -P rdeploy-staging clean package cargo:redeploy`
There is no error on console, but the app does not start on tomcat, it should be started on "/" root context.

This is my maven profile for remote deploy:

```xml
<profile>
        <id>rdeploy-staging</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources-staging</directory>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <copy file="${basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web_staging.xml"
                                        tofile="${basedir}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml" overwrite="true" />
                            </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Cargo Plug in -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Container configuration -->
                        <container>
                            <containerId>tomcat5x</containerId>
                            <type>remote</type>
                        </container>
                        <configuration>
                            <type>runtime</type>
                            <properties>
                                <cargo.remote.username>admin</cargo.remote.username>
                                <cargo.remote.password>admin</cargo.remote.password>
                                <cargo.hostname>server_ip</cargo.hostname>
                                <cargo.tomcat.manager.url>http://server_ip:8080/manager</cargo.tomcat.manager.url>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                        <deployables>
                            <deployable>
                                <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
                                <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
                                <type>war</type>
                            </deployable>
                        </deployables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

The output of tomcat standard error log:

> **INFO**: validateJarFile(C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\temp\1-ROOT\WEB-INF\lib\grizzly-servlet-webserver-1.9.35.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
>   Sep 19, 2012 1:48:47 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
>
> **INFO**: validateJarFile(C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\temp\1-ROOT\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
>   Sep 19, 2012 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>
> **SEVERE**: Error listenerStart
>   Sep 19, 2012 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>
> **SEVERE**: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors

Comment: Does it work if you deploy the application manually?

Comment: Yes, it works if you deploy by tomcat manager or just copy the ROOT.war into webapps directory. It also works if I deploy with cargo in my local machine, the problem happens when deploying using cargo in the staging server.